# Finding $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2-\cos \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}}$ using the cotangent function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I found the sum of this series using the $ \cot x $ function:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1-\cos \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1})}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\cot^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$$

> Question: Is it possible to find the sum of a new series using the $\cot x$ function?
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2-\cos \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}}=?$$

Comment: how did you find the sum equals to $\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$?

Comment: $$\sin \left( 2m+1 \right)\theta=\binom{2m+1}{1}\cos^{2m}\theta\sin \theta-\binom{2m+1}{3}\cos^{2m-2}\theta\sin^3\theta+\dots+(-1)^{m}\sin^{2m+1}\theta$$

Comment: Then he switched to cotangents and so he calculated the sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might as well solve it for a free variable, which is performed now.
From Hansen, Table of Series and Products, entry 91.2.10 specialized to odd integers,

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \cosh{y} - \cos{ \big(\frac{2 \pi k}{2n+1} \big)} = 2^{-n} 
\frac{\sinh{\big((n+1/2)y\big)}}{\sinh{\big(y/2\big)}} $$

Do a logarithmic derivative on both sides and simplify:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{ \cosh{y} - \cos{ \big(\frac{2 \pi k}{2n+1} }\big) } =
\frac{1}{\sinh{y}}\Big( (n+1/2)\coth{\big((n+1/2)y\big)}  -  1/2\coth{\big(y/2\big)} \Big)$$

The OP's solution is for $y=$arccosh(2).